# Selenium is unable to detect the Checkout button and add product in cart

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

The problem is, Selenium is unable to detect the Checkout button and add product in cart.

```
    package automationFramework;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Checkout {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://sng.bestpricewebsitedesign.com/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 

  }

  @Test
  public void testNewCheckout() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/index.php?route=common/home");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Home")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Login")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("input-email")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("input-email")).sendKeys("leo@abc.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("input-password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("input-password")).sendKeys("asdfgh");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.btn.btn-primary")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Store")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[14]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#cart > button.dropdown-toggle")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.id("button-payment-address")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("button-shipping-address")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("button-shipping-method")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("agree")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("button-payment-method")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("button-confirm")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Continue")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logout")).click();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }

  private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
      driver.switchTo().alert();
      return true;
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
      Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      String alertText = alert.getText();
      if (acceptNextAlert) {
        alert.accept();
      } else {
        alert.dismiss();
      }
      return alertText;
    } finally {
      acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please do not ask people to do your work for your here. Stack Overflow is a source of volunteer assistance, not free labour.

Comment: I have tried everything and nothing seems to fix issue. well I am not asking for digging hole........

Comment: It is a popular view that writing code is "not real work", but that opinion is wrong. Designers and artists often are asked to work for free too, and yet we would not dream of asking a person to undertake manual labour - say digging a hole - without payment. Ultimately it is a question of wording - `someone fix it` is not an acceptable instruction to issue to volunteers. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the code for adding 'Blue Tshirt' in cart and perform check out.

```
@Test
public void testNewCheckout() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/index.php?route=common/home");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Home")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Login")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("input-email")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("input-email")).sendKeys("leo@abc.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("input-password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("input-password")).sendKeys("asdfgh");
    //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.btn.btn-primary")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Login']")).click();;
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Store")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h4/a[text()='Blue Tshirt']/following::span[text()='Add to Cart'][1]")).click();
    //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#cart > button.dropdown-toggle")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='cart']/button[1]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("button-payment-address")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("button-shipping-address")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("button-shipping-method")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("agree")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("button-payment-method")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("button-confirm")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Continue")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logout")).click();
}
```

I have tested above code and it works fine for me. Please replace the existing test method with above one and let me know, if it works for you.

Comment: No, its not working. I have replaced, 
I am facing 2 issues. 
1. product is not adding in cart, and 2nd checkout page is not opening blow two lines having issues..

driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[14]")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#cart > button.dropdown-toggle")).click();

Comment: Great. You are welcome. If you are satisfied with my answer, could you please accept my answer and mark it as useful :-)

Comment: @Mahipal can you explain below noted line from above answer, 

By.xpath("//h4/a[text()='Blue Tshirt']/following::span[text()='Add to Cart'][1]")

What is this path, want to understand this pattern.

Comment: @DasKhatri `By.xpath("//h4/a[text()='Blue Tshirt']/following::span[text()='Add to Cart'][1]")` means, find any 'h4' tag which has child(/) 'a' with text property as 'Blue Tshirt', and then, find the first([1]) instance of 'span' tag which comes after(following::) 'a' with text property as ''Add to Cart'. Let me know, if you have any further queries.